# In c#, add commands to PowerShell InitialSessionState using script and make them discoverable from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-hosting

Is there a way to find functions that were imported into an InitialSessionState using ImportPSModule()?

I have this wrapper around PowerShell to run scripts self-hosted by my applicaton (comments and error checking removed for brevity)

```
public class Engine
{
    private readonly InitialSessionState sessionState;

    public Engine(string initializationModulePath)
    {
        this.sessionState = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        this.sessionState.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;
        this.sessionState.AuthorizationManager = null;
        // New functionality - allow an initialization file.
        this.sessionState.ImportPSModule(new[] { initializationModulePath });
    }

    public void AddCommand(String name, Type implementingType) => this.sessionState.Commands.Add(
            new SessionStateCmdletEntry(
                name,
                implementingType,
                null));

    public void RunScript(string script, string scriptComment)
    {
        using (PowerShell powerShellCommand = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShellCommand.AddScript(script);

            using (powerShellCommand.Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(this.sessionState))
            {
                powerShellCommand.Runspace.Open();
                Collection<PSObject> results = powerShellCommand.Invoke();
                // Results processing omitted.
            }
        }
    }

    // Testing - I see things added via AddCommand() but not anything imported via ImportPSModule
    public void ListCommands()
    {
        foreach (SessionStateCommandEntry commandEntry in this.sessionState.Commands)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Command: {commandEntry.Name}, Type: {commandEntry.CommandType}");
        }
    }
}
```

When I add types using engine.AddCommand(), they show up in engine.ListCommands() as expected.  I now want to allow users to have a custom set of functions they've predefine which I'll import via ImportPSModule().  Finally, I'd like to be able to list out those commands in the UI as commands that are available.

I created a really simple module (init.psm1)

```
function Add-Number {[CmdletBinding()] param ([int]$a, [int]$b) $a + $b }
function Subtract-Number {[CmdletBinding()] param ([int]$a, [int]$b) $a - $b }
```

and tested importing it, but the functions don't show up as available commands. (Though user scripts can use them just fine.)

I looked at System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser.ParseFile based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390833/how-to-discover-powershell-script-parameters-in-c-sharp) and could check for tokens after {function}, but it seems like a round-about way to do it. (Currently, this is the best option I have.)

I considered running a little script with `Get-ChildItem function:`, but Get-ChildItem is not available when using `InitialSessionState.CreateDefault()` (I do not want to use  `InitialSessionState.Create()`.  My scenario requires the engine to be more locked down than that.)

Is there another option I can use to get the list of user-defined functions?  Importing them in another manner is acceptable so long as users can provide them as powershell code.

Thanks!

**Edit**
Re-reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.initialsessionstate.importpsmodule?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), it seems I had missed this very important line:

```
Add a list of modules to import when the runspace is created.
```

So I'll update the question a little to be "Is there an way to create a SessionStateCommandEntry() from a script file that can be added to initialSessionState.Commands?"

Comment: Try adding `Export-Module -Function Add-Number,Subtract-Number` to the `psm1` file

Comment: Thanks. I gave that a shot but no luck.  I've updated the question to reflect a key piece of documentation I missed (when the module is executed) and clarified that what I seem to need as a way to create a SessionStateCommandEntry() using a *.psm1 as the input.